# Pausing for loop after every execution

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-ajax, settimeout

i have a page, wherein i am using a ajax for inserting records... now in javascript i am using a for each loop to loop the html table and insert the rows in database. but happens is as foreach loop executes fast, it sometime, does not insert some records.. so i want to make the loop sleep for sometime once it has executed first and thereafter...

is there any way to pause the for loop.. i used setTImeout.. but it just delay it first time and not consecutive times...
here's my code.

```
     function AddTopStories() {
            $("#tBodySecond tr").each(function (index) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "AjaxMethods.aspx/AddTopStoriesPosition",
                    data: "{'articleID':'" + $("td:nth-child(1)", this).text() + "','siteID':1}",
                    dataType: "json",
                    contentType: "application/json",
                    success: function (data) {
                        window.setTimeout(showSuccessToast(data.d), 3000);
                    },
                    error: function (data) {
                        window.setTimeout(showSuccessToast("Error:" + data.reponseText), 3000);
                    }
                });
            });
        }

Please help me to resolve this issue... its utmost important.
*************************************UPDATED CODE AS PER THE CHANGES BY jfriend00*********

function AddTopStories() {
    var stories = $("#tBodySecond tr");
    var storyIndex = 0;

    function addNext() {
        if (storyIndex > stories.length) return;   // done, no more to get
        var item = stories.get(storyIndex++);
        alert($("td:nth-child(1)", item).text());
        addNext();
    }
}
```

This just does not do anything... does not alert...

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend you break it into a function that does one story and then you initiate the next story from the success handler of the first like this:

```
function AddTopStories() {
    var stories = $("#tBodySecond tr");
    var storyIndex = 0;

    function addNext() {
        if (storyIndex >= stories.length) return;   // done, no more to get
        var item = stories.get(storyIndex++);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "AjaxMethods.aspx/AddTopStoriesPosition",
            data: "{'articleID':'" + $("td:nth-child(1)", item).text() + "','siteID':1}",
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json",
            success: function (data) {
                addNext();          // upon success, do the next story
                showSuccessToast(data.d);
            },
            error: function (data) {
                showSuccessToast("Error:" + data.reponseText);
            }
        });
    }
    addNext();
}
```

Comment: i updated my question, i have added the code which you provided me.. check my question... under UPDATED CODE AS PER THE CHANGES BY jfriend00.. but it just does not do anything.

Comment: I forgot one line that I just added.  You have to call `addNext()` the first time.

Comment: you are just awesome man.... what a code... just to great.. never thought that it could be done.. without loop and timeout.... superb man.... thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Ugly, but you can fake a javascript 'sleep' using one of the methods on this website:

http://www.devcheater.com/